# Java: How do you add data into an object?

Tags: java, string, object, constructor, addition

I'm new to Java. How do you add String data into an Object "`myData`" and print out the contents of it in main?

```
public class myData {
  static String[] myArray = new String[] { "Mimi Rudolph", "minirudolph" };

  public static String[] cutName(String string) {
    return string.split(" ");
  }

  String[] fullName = cutName(myArray[0]);
  String skype = myArray[1];
  String github = null;
  Object myData = new Object();

  public myData(String[] fullName, String skype, String github) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.skype = skype;
    this.github = github;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object myData = new Object();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tai, I think you're missing some concepts in your code.
Once Java is an Object Oriented Programming language, you should avoid using the `static` in your methods when you want to have a new instance of a class.

To call methods with `static`, you don't need a new instance of an object (can call it as `MyData.cutName`, for example.

On the other hand, constructors will be accessed when you create a new instance of your object.

I believe you can get rid of the arrays, but I kept it in your `cutName` method.
You could have something like this.

```
public class MyData {
    private String fullname;
    private String skype;
    private String github;

    public MyData(String fullname, String skype, String github) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.skype = skype;
        this.github = github;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return this.fullname;
    }

    public String getSkype() {
        return this.skype;
    }

    public String getGithub() {
        return this.github;
    }

    public String[] cutName(String string) {
        return string.split(" ");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fullname: " + this.fullname + "; Skype: " + this.skype + "; Github: " + this.github;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyData myData = new MyData("Mimi Rudolph", "minirudolph_skype", "minirudolph_githnub");
        System.out.println("First name: " + myData.cutName(myData.getFullname())[0]);
        System.out.println("Last name: " + myData.cutName(myData.getFullname())[1]);
        System.out.println(myData);
    }
}
```

The output would be:

```
First name: Mimi
Last name: Rudolph
Fullname: Mimi Rudolph; Skype: minirudolph_skype; Github: minirudolph_githnub
```

Having the attributes in your class and setting it from the new instance will help you to have reusability.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply create an instance of your class `myData` as next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myData myData = new myData(myArray, "skype", "github");
    ...
}
```

To print its content you could override the method `toString()` for example like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "myData{" +
        "fullName=" + Arrays.toString(fullName) +
        ", skype='" + skype + '\'' +
        ", github='" + github + '\'' +
        ", myData=" + myData +
        '}';
}
```

Then you will be able to print its content using `System.out.println(myData)`.

So the final code would look like this:

```
public class myData {
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myData myData = ...
        System.out.println(myData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public class MyData {

private static final String[] myArray = new String[]{"Mimi Rudolph", "minirudolph"};

String[] fullName = cutName(myArray[0]);
String skype = myArray[1];
String github = null;
Object myData = new Object();

private static String[] cutName(String string) {
    return string.split(" ");
}

public MyData(String[] fullName, String skype, String github) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.skype = skype;
    this.github = github;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyData myData = new MyData(myArray, "Skype string goes here", "githun string goes here");
    System.out.println(myData.fullName);
    System.out.println(myData.github);
    System.out.println(myData.skype);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can add string to object by the following simple example:

```
 String a = "abc";
 Object b = a;
 System.out.println(b);
```

If you want to assign a complete String array to myData Object, then you need to do the following:

```
 Object[] myData  = new Object[myArray.length];
        for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
            myData [i] = myArray[i];
            System.out.println("MyData Object Array holding strings data: "+myData[i]);
        }
```

In you main method, you need to change object to object of Arrays first:
From - `Object myData = new Object();`
TO: `Object[] myData  = new Object[myArray.length];`